# Errors While Loading Mono (Embeded)

Tags: c++, mono

I'm trying to embed Mono in my C/C++ application framework (game engine), but I have troubles trying to run it: I get the following error

```
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
It should have been installed in the 'G:\Users\MattMatt\Workspace\SpikyEngine\lib\mono\4.5\mscorlib.dll' directory'.
```

The issue is I can't find any files by the name of `mscorlib.dll` in my mono installation directory; any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
#include "../include/Spiky/System/Log.h"
#include <mono/jit/jit.

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MonoDomain *domain;
    domain = mono_jit_init("test");

    MonoAssembly *assembly;
    assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "file.exe");
    if (!assembly)
    {
        SPIKY_LOG(spiky::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR) 
            << "@Mono Couldn't load assembly code from 'file.exe'";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. All I needed was to point to the mono assembly directory, this way:

```
mono_set_dirs("...\\Mono\\lib", "...\\Mono\\etc");
```